# PostgreSQL - how to have the 0 values using a WHERE?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am currently working on PostgreSQL having 2 data tables : item and order.

I want to display the number of order for each item in a period of time, but i would like to keep the name displayed if it's 0.

i'm actually doing:

```
SELECT Item.name, count(Order.id) from Item
INNER JOIN Order ON Item.id = Order.it_id
WHERE Order.date > '01/08/2021'
```

The problem is that my results are:

```
Chocolate | 1
Cake | 2
Muffin | 3
```

And i would like to have:

```
Chocolate | 1
Cake | 2
Muffin | 3
Pancake | 0
Donut | 0
```

I have used a RIGHT JOIN that is working without my WHERE condition but i need to filter with the date for my results values.

Maybe i'm not in the good way to do it.
I don't know if it is possible or if there an other way to do it.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your query should return an error because it has no `group by`.

Second, you want a `left join`:

```
SELECT i.name, COUNT(o.id)
FROM Item i LEFT JOIN
     Order o
     ON i.id = o.it_id AND
        o.date >= '2021-01-08'
GROUP BY i.name;
```

Also notice that the date is in a standard format and the condition moves to the `ON` clause.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try it as soon as possible (i have forgot to copy the group by, but i used one)